# Tables using LIKE may only reference flat structures

Tags: abap, saprfc

I wanna have a table parameter in a RFC function module of type `CGPL_TEXT1`, which uses the domain type `TEXT40`, which is a char 40.

I tried to create it:

`IT_PARTS_DESCRIPTION   LIKE    CGPL_TEXT1`

But I keep getting this error

> tables using like may only reference flat structures

I am also not able to use `TYPE`. If I do so, I get this error:

> Flat types may only be referenced using LIKE for table parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't go there. For RFC-enabled function modules, always use a structure as a line type for your table. The RFC protocol itself also supports unstructured tables, but many adapters don't. So you should

- declare a data dictionary structure Z_MY_PARTS_DATA with a single field DESCRIPTION TYPE CGPL_TEXT2
- declare a data dictionary table type Z_MY_PARTS_TABLE using this structure
- use that table type in your function module.

Answer (score 1):

Look inside the dictionary for a table type which has only one column representing Your Text.
If You cannot find it, just go the proper way and define a z structure and a z tabletype based on that structure. This is the proper way and I also prefer to use this ( even sometimes, when I  would not really need it, i do this ).... because the structures sand table types can be documented.